# Java, Is it possible to pass in 2 objects into a method to do something to them?

Tags: java

[image]

[image]

In psuedo code, I think

```
 public static double Timedifference(Objectt 1, object 2)
{take the difference of both variables of obj 1 and obj 2 and return a double}
```

T**he logic behind choosing double as the return type:**
 I wish I could return 2 values for my method difference. It would make life easier since I could just return difference of minutes and hours individually. I can't do that. what I'm thinking is instead, is to convert the time object arguments into decimals, and then return the decimal. After that perhaps, using another method which would take in that decimal and convert back into hours and minutes.

Or....  maybe I'm just overthinking maybe I could use a method with no return type, make it to the difference, and print the difference?

Here is the relevent code that I've made for the objects.

```
   // Double parameter 
class Time {
  int hours,minutes;
  double number,temp;

  public Time(int x,int y){
    hours= x;
    minutes=y;

    hours+=minutes/60;
    minutes%= 60;
  }
  //Single parameter 
  public Time(double input){
    number=  input;
    double temp ;


    temp=  (number%1*60*100)/100; 
    minutes= (int)temp;
    hours= (int)number-(int)number%1;

  }
```

Comment: You can always return array of Time class, can't you?

Comment: You can create a POJO with all the properties you need and return it instead.

Comment: In your code it's not necessary to make temp and number a field of the class since you only use them in the constructor.

Comment: You can have a method which takes two arguments, or 128 arguments, or none.  You can return a value. You appear to have what should be two unrelated classes.

Comment: Your requirement is to return a Time object so I don't think you can get by with returning a double.

Comment: For difference, all you need to do is calculate the time difference between two Time objects. That difference will be a certain number of minutes/hours which is exactly what Time is supposed to contain. Maybe I'm missing something but it seems straightforward.

Comment: I would convert each Time into a number of minutes, do the subtraction, then convert to hours/minutes and store in a new Time object

Comment: It will easy to implement this if you keep track of the type of time object : `Hour:Min` or `duration`. One way to track it is by checking which of these is set and have default value e.g. `Integer.MIN_VALUE` to indicate `UNSET` but you could as well have a Boolean flag indicate `Time Type`, then you simply return a Time object with subtracted times and the type using computed values or a flag.

Comment: Just return a double: Integer part  = hours, decimal part = minutes. Or create an wrapper object to return as many values as you please. Oh, you have one already, it's called `Time`.

Answer (score 0):

In Java, you may pass as many objects as you like to a method but may only return a single object from a method.  So, you cannot return both hours and minutes from a method.  For this reason, you will create a Time object and return this object from your method.

Answering the question with Time as a period of time (minutes) would be easier than time of day (10:15):

```
class Time {
    int hours, minutes, periodOfTime;
    public class Time (int hours, int minutes) {
        this.hours = hours;
        this.minutes = minutes;
        periodOfTime = //calculate your time period from the hrs/mins given;
    }
    //put three getter methods here for minutes, hours, periodOfTime
    public static Time difference(Time t1, Time t2) {
        //calculate your differences here using the getter methods
        //create a new Time object that represents the difference
        //return the new Time object
    }
```

Not part of the question, but then you could do a System.out.println("Difference was: " + time.getPeriodOfTime()); to display the answer.
This will avoid having to convert to a double, then back to int of minutes/hours.  You keep everything in the Time Object and access it when you need to with the getter methods.